# How to create a function that have the functionality of helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer but with added opened org files?

Tags: org-mode, buffers, helm, projectile

I really like helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer as it shows buffers for the specific project I am working in (i have multiple projects open at the same time). But I also rely on org files for notes and debug information.

How is it possible to create a function that performs the exact same functionality of helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer but add to the possible buffers to switch to the opened org files as well?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define a class that inherits from the `helm-source-buffers` class. You can use the candidate-transformer slot to remove non-Org buffers from the list. Then add the new source to the list of sources in your custom command.

```
(defclass helm-source-org-buffers (helm-source-buffers)
  ((candidate-transformer :initform (lambda (buffers)
                                      (cl-loop for b in buffers
                                               when (eq (with-current-buffer b
                                                          major-mode)
                                                        'org-mode)
                                               collect b)))))

(defvar helm-source-org-buffers-list nil)

(defun your-helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (unless helm-source-org-buffers-list
    (setq helm-source-org-buffers-list
          (helm-make-source "Org Buffers" 'helm-source-org-buffers)))
  (helm :sources '(helm-source-projectile-buffers-list
                   helm-source-org-buffers-list)))
```